# UnECM isn't working, returning "command not found"

Tags: command-line, apt

I'm trying to get the `unecm` command of ecm tools to work, and I installed it through `apt-get`. It keeps returning `command not found` when I try to run it. I looked in Synaptic, and it says that it is installed, and reinstalling it doesn't help.

For full disclosure, I am running the newest Xubuntu distro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just tested it out, here's your issue: You should be using `ecm-uncompress`

How I found the issue:

`dpkg -L [PACKAGE NAME]` shows all files that were installed by a certain package. In this case, with `dpkg -L ecm` it shows:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/ecm-compress
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/ecm
/usr/share/doc/ecm/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/ecm/copyright
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/fr
/usr/share/man/fr/man1
/usr/share/man/fr/man1/ecm-uncompress.1.gz
/usr/share/man/fr/man1/ecm-compress.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/ecm-uncompress.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/ecm-compress.1.gz
/usr/bin/ecm-uncompress
```

Chiefly of note there are the ones in the `/usr/bin` directory:

```
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/ecm-compress
/usr/bin/ecm-uncompress
```

These are the only 'commands' that were installed by the package (aside from `man ecm-uncompress ecm-compress`

Answer (score 1):

You can install ecm using the command `apt-get install ecm`. Use another command to unecm the file:`ecm-uncompress file-name.bin.ecm`. It's easier if you just type `ecm-uncompress` then drag the `file.bin.ecm` into the terminal. It worked for me.